# How to create a link in the highlights panel of the console to the contact detail page?

Tags: configuration, servicecloud

I am trying to create a link for the name of the employee in the Highlights Panel of the console so that it opens the Contact Detail page for the employee within the console to allow me to see additional details.

Comment: Is the employee is a Contact?